# are there any other ways to sort null lists in python?

Tags: python, sorting, null, opencsv

Is there other ways to sort a list without using  lambda?

I have my code

```
import csv

def menu_list(filep): #function menu list path file

    menulists = []

    with open(filep) as csv_file: #read csv file
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_reader:
            mList = []
            for i in range (len(row)):
                mList.append(row[i])
            menulists.append(mList)

    menulists.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
    return menulists
```

I just want to know if there are any other ways to sort a null list

Comment: What do you mean by "null list"? If you don't like using a lambda expression you can replace it with `operator.itemgetter(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you have in this csv_file, but I think that in this case you should use `pandas`.

something like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_csv)
df = df.sort_values(by=['col_name'])
```